# Comment dire "It was not until my time at.." en français?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, constructions

Est-ce quelqu'un sait comment dire "It was not until my time at..." en français?

Par exemple, "It was not until my time at this place that I realized..."

Comment: "C'est à compter/partir du moment passé à cet endroit que..." ou "Ce n'est pas avant d'avoir passé..." par exemple.

Comment: @MorganFR ça resemble à une réponse ça non... ? :)

Comment: Je ne connais pas cette expression, pouvez vous rajouter des exemples ou en expliquer plus précisément le sens ?

Comment: @Random Ce n'est pas tout à fait une réponse, mais plutôt une piste, et je ne précise rien pour argumenter. Je préfère donc ne pas envisager ça comme une réponse complète.

Comment: Just another "piste," as this will be of no help with the “my time at” part of your question, but (especially if you’re no longer there) you could consider using the “ne..que” construction in your sentence, such as: “**Je ne me suis rendu compte/je n’ai réalisé qu’après** + [my time at …] que [whatever was realized])” to capture the “until [after]” part of it. If the particular place (including a hint that you’re no longer there) & the "realization" have just been previously mentioned you could maybe just use: “[I was happy (during my time) at IBM] mais **je ne l'ai réalisé qu’après** [coup]."

Answer (score 3):

To keep a maximal parallelism with your structure you could use this structure:

- *Ce n'est qu'en arrivant à ... que je me suis rendu compte de/que ...*